# Lambdas in Boo?

Tags: syntax, lambda, boo

How do you deal with lambdas in boo? Is "callable" the same thing? How do you define a method that takes a lambda as a parameter?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Boo does support lambda expression syntax:

```
foo = {x|x+2}
seven = foo(5)
def TakeLambda(expr as callable(int) as int):
   return expr(10)
twelve = TakeLambda(foo)
```

In this example, `foo` is a function that accepts a number x and returns x + 2. So calling `foo(5)` returns the number 7. `TakeLambda` is a function that accepts `foo` and evaluates it at 10.

Comment: Thanks, i see most cases just "as callable" is enough

Comment: I wish .NET delegates were more like callable in boo. this would make life so much easier in so many cases...

Comment: @Krzysztof Koźmic: F#'s notation is nice: `TakeLambda : (int -> int) -> int`